# SnowFlake Query Processing Time Complexity

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract 20k records by using tablesample clause( select * from tablename sample ROW(20000 rows);)

I have following question:

How does this sample query does work like does it pick random rows while scanning all rows(Like suppose it picks 1st row then ignore 2nd,3rd,4th... and picks kth rows and picks similarly other rows in the same fashion )or randomly it picks like 1st,2nd then directly 4th then directly kth...,

2. What is time complexity of running query is :O(200000) or O(n) {n is total rows}.?

Answer (score 0):

Let's run an experiment to answer this question, using 4 tables with exponentially more data:

[image]

This is how long it took to get 10 random rows from each:

```sql
select * 
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf001.customer sample row(10) 
--0.1s
;

select * 
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer sample row(10) 
--0.46s
;

select * 
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.customer sample row(10) 
--1.2s
;

select * 
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf100.customer sample row(10) 
--3.1s
;
```

It's clear that the time to get 10 random rows with `sample row(10)` increases as the tables grow.

We can visualize it too:

[image]

```sql
select count(*), 'tpch_sf001', 0.1 seconds from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf001.customer
union all select count(*), 'tpch_sf1', 0.46 from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer
union all select count(*), 'tpch_sf10', 1.2 from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf10.customer
union all select count(*), 'tpch_sf100', 3.1 from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf100.customer;
```